# How does the dominator object may lack references to an object it dominates?

Tags: javascript, object, google-chrome-devtools, heap-memory, heap-profiling

I was going through the documentation of chrome dev tools. 
On this [page](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/memory-analysis-101) on memory analysis it said :

> Dominator objects comprise a tree structure, because each object has exactly one dominator. A dominator of an object may lack direct references to an object it dominates, that is, the dominators tree is not a spanning tree of the graph.

I was not able to get it because how did the parent object became a dominator of the child without referencing the child object. I mean somewhere in the code it would have been written like this:

`var parent = {child : child};
   var child = {name : 'child'};`

That is how parent became a dominator of the child.

But now it says that the dominator may lack references to the child. Can anyone give me an example situation for this case.

Answer (score 0):

That documentation page doesn't say that it should be a direct parent:

> dominator of an object A is an object that exists in every simple path from the root to the object A.

So the dominator may reference other objects that reference the target and thus the condition `dominator of an object may lack direct references` is true.